# Python: Multiple One-Argument Constructors

Tags: python

I have a `Game` class which has a field that's a `Board` object.  I currently make a `Game` by passing in a string encoding information about the game and making the `Board` object.

However, I now have a bunch of `Board` objects and want to make a new constructor that takes in the `Board` object directly.

Here's my current constructor:

```
def __init__(self, game_string):
    self.single_list = game_string.split(",")
    self.board = self.parse_game_string(game_string)
    self.directions = self.get_all_directions()
    self.red_number_of_streaks = self.get_number_of_streaks("R")
    self.black_number_of_streaks = self.get_number_of_streaks("B")
```

But now I have the board object, so I'd like to just do:

```
def __init__(self, board):
    self.board = board
    self.directions = self.get_all_directions()
    self.red_number_of_streaks = self.get_number_of_streaks("R")
    self.black_number_of_streaks = self.get_number_of_streaks("B")
```

I don't think Python will know how to distinguish between these two constructors.  I *could* determine what to do based on the type of argument?  Something like:

if isinstance(str):
    # usual constructor functionality
elif isinstance(Game):
    # new constructor functionality

Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would do it like this:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, board):
        ...

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, game_string):
        board = cls.parse_game_string(game_string)
        game = cls(board)
        game.something = 5

        return game

    @staticmethod
    def parse_game_string(game_string):
        ...

        return Board(...)
```

`Game.from_string` would then construct an instance of `Game` out of a string, using the default `Game` initializer which accepts a `Board` object.

You will have to make `Game.parse_game_string` a static method for it to be usable from the `Game.from_string` class method.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the type of input is certainly an option:

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, str_or_board):
        if isinstance(str_or_board, Board):
            board = str_or_board
        else:
            board = self.parse_game_string(str_or_board)

        self.board = board
```

Instead of `isinstance`, [duck typing](https://docs.python.org/dev/glossary.html#term-duck-typing) is also an option.

Alternatively, you can use a factory function:

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, board):
        assert isinstance(board, Board)
        self.board = board

    @classmethod
    def fromstring(cls, board_str):
        return cls(self.parse_game_string(board_str))

# Use like ...
game1 = Game(Board())
game2 = Game.fromstring('foobar')
```

Answer (score 2):

For method overloading in Python, you can pass both arguments (`game_string`, `board`) to the `__init__` initializing them as None.

You can then have one constructor such as:

```
def __init__(self, game_string=None, board=None):
    self.single_list = game_string.split(",")
    self.board = self.parse_game_string(game_string) if game_string else board
    self.directions = self.get_all_directions()
    self.red_number_of_streaks = self.get_number_of_streaks("R")
    self.black_number_of_streaks = self.get_number_of_streaks("B")
```

If `game_string` is provided it will be used as the board. Otherwise, the `board` argument will be used.